# What are the relations between columns and Subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $A$ be a $2\times 4$ matrix. For which columns $B$ is $U = \{X ∈ \Bbb R^4\mid  AX=B\}$ a subspace of $\Bbb R^4$?

I honestly don't really know what the relation between the columns of a matrix have with its subspace, even more so due to the fact that $A$ or $X$ isn't specified either. Can anyone help me out with where to start with this? Might genuinely be the most obtuse question I've seen in a while!

Comment: Note the statement "for which columns $B$" does **not** mean "which columns of $A$", it means "which column vectors", i.e. which vectors $B \in \Bbb R^2$. Once you have parsed the question correctly, I think you'll find the following hint useful: in order to be a subspace, a set must contain the zero-vector.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why you find the question to be obtuse, it looks like a cute question to me

Comment: @BenGrossmann I see what you did there

Comment: Where to start: You have the definition of $U$. Does it satisfy all the conditions for a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ to be a subspace?

Comment: How would I test that for the columns though?

Comment: B would be a 2x1 Matrix but I don't know where else to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Since $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$, we can apply the subspace criterion. We have that $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ if and only if the three lines below are all true.
$$0 \in U$$
$$u+v \in U \quad \forall u,v \in U$$
$$\lambda u \in U \quad \forall u \in U \; \text{and} \; \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$$

Note that in the case of $A$ being the zero matrix it trivially follows that $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ if and only if $B$ is the zero vector. So let us continue by assuming that $A$ is not the zero matrix.

Firstly, we require that the zero vector is in $U$. By the definition of $U$, this can only be true if $B=0$, since otherwise $X=0$ would not be a solution to the equation $AX=B$, as $A$ is not the zero matrix.

We will now claim and prove that when $A$ is not the zero matrix, $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ if and only if $B=0$.

$Proof.$

To prove the forward implication, assume that $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then, $u+v \in U$ for some $u,v \in U$. By the definition of $U$, $Au=B$ and $Av=B$ and also $A(u+v)=B$. So,

\begin{align}
B & = Au+Av \\
& = B + B \\
& = 2B \\
\end{align}

It follows that $B=0$, proving the forward implication.

The reverse implication is trivial. Suppose $B=0$. Then, $U$ is the trivial vector space, which indeed is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

So we conclude that for any $2 \times 4$ matrix $A$, $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ if and only if $B=0$ (i.e., the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$).